# Bash Script for Cisco devices

Tags: bash, shell, cisco

i trying to do a bash script that connects to Cisco Switches and print the output in a file created with name --> TimestampDeviceXX_Check.txt
and after compare the outputs to see if there are differences in the output files. (they must be the same because their config must be aligned).

I've already the scripts  for connect to the switches so  i only have to lauch the xxx.sh to log in the device.

here is the idea that i want to create and i ll appreciate if you help me:

I'm new to bash scripting  and certanly i know that i did some errors.... i hope that you ll help me

Thanks, Regards T. :)

```
#!/bin/bash

devices="
./Shop1/Sw1-ab2.sh  
./Shop2/Sw1-cd1.sh  
./Shop3/Sw1-ef1.sh  
"


outdir=$(./Check/$(date +%Y%m%d)/Check_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).dir)

for device in $devices; do

        logfile=${outdir}/$(basename ${device} .sh).txt
        if[! -e $logfile] ; then
                touch $logfile
        fi
        expect <<- END > ${logfile}
                spawn "${device}"
                expect "#"
                send "terminal length 0\r"
                expect "*#"
                send "show running-config | begin mac access-list extended \n"
                expect "#"
                send "show mac address-table vlan xx\n"
                expect "#"
                send "show mac address-table vlan xx\n"
                expect "#"
                send "exit\r"
                expect closed

        END

        echo ${device}
        echo "==================================="
        echo
>done
```

Comment: what's the output of your script? any errors?

Comment: i'm getting the message " directory not exists"

Comment: can you edit your question with the output?

Comment: Sorry i didn t understand your answer..

Comment: copy and paste whatever your script is printing to your screen, so everyone can see what's wrong.

Comment: You probably just need to do `mkdir -p ${outdir}` after the `outdir=...` line. Unless some other process is creating the date/time folders ahead of time, this would explain the "directory does not exist" errors.

Comment: Just like this ? outdir=mkdir -p ${outdir+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create files in a directory that does not exist yet. You can fix this by using `mkdir` to create the directory before trying to write files there. Add a `mkdir -d ${outdir}` call after the `outdir=...` line in your script, like so:

```
outdir=$(./Check/$(date +%Y%m%d)/Check_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).dir)
mkdir -p ${outdir}
```

Comment: Thanks i ll edit the script than i ll post new updates about it

Comment: line 11: ./Check/20140521/Check_20140521100217.dir: No such file or directory
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
./script.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./script.sh: line 17: `        if[! -e $logfile] ; then'

Answer (score 0):

This is the output:

line 11: ./Check/20140521/Check_20140521100217.dir: No such file or directory mkdir: missing operand Try mkdir --help' for more information. ./script.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token then' ./script.sh: line 17: ` if[! -e $logfile] ; then